# $I$ be a finitely generated ideal of $R$ such that $R/I$ is a Noetherian and $R$ is $I$-adically complete. Then $R$ is Noetherian

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, topological-rings

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $I$ be a finitely generated ideal of $R$ such that  $R/I$ is a Noetherian ring and $R$ is complete with the $I$-adic topology. Then how to show that $R$ is Noetherian ?

I have no clue about where to start. The only thing I can see is that $\cap_{n\ge 1} I^n=(0)$ since $R$ is $I$-adic complete.

Please help.

Comment: Can you show this if $I$ is principal?

Comment: I am not sure that the condition "$I$-adic complete" is needed for this.

Comment: @user213008: I am not sure what you mean ... certainly there are non-Noetherian rings $R$ with finitely generated ideal $I$ such that $R/I$ is Noetherian ...

Comment: @users What you can prove is that the associated graded ring $\operatorname{gr}_I R$ is noetherian. Now the question is: How to pass from $\operatorname{gr}_I R$ to $R$ itself. Right, $I$-adic complete is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the proof in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05GH starting with "let $f_1, \ldots, f_t$ be generators of $I$."